# How to reorder a dataframe's columns to have a specific column as first column?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

i have a df with columns name that are: `['AA', 'BB', 'DD']`

I have a variable name that is:
`col_name = 'BB'`

How can I reorder the columns of my dataframe in such a way that it will be (col_name as the 1st column):
`['BB', 'AA', 'DD']`

Answer (score 0):

You can use an [`Index.intersection`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Index.intersection.html) without sorting the columns:

```
col_name = 'BB'

out = df[pd.Index([col_name]).union(df.columns, sort=False)]
```

If `col_name` is not necessarily present in the DataFrame rather [`reindex`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html):

```
out = df.reindex(columns=pd.Index([col_name]).union(df.columns, sort=False))
```

Output:

```
    BB   AA   DD
0  NaN  NaN  NaN
```